# Avoiding duplicate deletion in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am removing lines from a bunch of txt files using regex using Python; however, I came across a case where it sometimes does a duplicate deletion if the line contains a string fairly similar to the first one

```
s = 'market.fruit.apple'
```

The txt file might contain the following lines

```
market.fruit.apple
market.fruit.apple.all
```

But if I run

```
open_file = open('test.txt', 'r')
read_file = open_file.read()
r = re.compile(r"(?<!\S){0}.*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(s))
read_file = r.sub('',read_file)
write_file = open('test.txt', 'w')
write_file.write(read_file)
```

it removes both `market.fruit.apple` and `market.fruit.apple.all` when only the first one should be removed. How do I avoid it? I tried setting the count parameter to 1 but that didn't do anything. I was thinking of doing a string similarity between the strings and use a different regex if it matches the right condition but I figured this might be unneccesary overhead if I scale this up.

Edit: Corrected some typos in the example above, can be repro in regex101.com/r/q7qWVh/1

Comment: `(?<!\S)` and `(?:[\r\n]\s*)?` could maybe be simplified with `^`, `$`, and/or `\b`.

Comment: Show us the whole relevant code. Even if you do not escape the literal string properly (which you should have done with `re.escape(s)`) [it does not remove extra text](https://regex101.com/r/USIoTt/1)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with this example.

Comment: Updated above, the txt file is more or less an example of what I'm dealing with but what i've described is the gist of what i've been running into

Comment: The gist is not enough, it is not repro.

Comment: Oh... woops I noticed I made some typos @WiktorStribiżew to my example. I'll edit

Comment: Made edits , https://regex101.com/r/q7qWVh/1 this shows it removes both now

Comment: Use `r"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S).*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(re.escape(s))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works but it fails in another case if there's any delimiters after the target string without whitespace such as `market.fruit.apple=3` but will work for `market.fruit.apple = 3`

Comment: Then use `r"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w).*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(re.escape(s))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that still removes both strings . Would just using the word similarity score as a condition work better

Comment: You need to reconsider your boundaries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , just resolved it! re.compile(r"(?<!\S){0}(=|\s).*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(s)) worked for me . Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r"(?<!\S){0}[\s=].*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?".format(re.escape(s))
```

Note the use `re.escape`, it is necessary since you are using a variable representing literal text into the regex pattern.

If your variable is `market.fruit.apple`, your regex will look like

```
(?<!\S)market\.fruit\.apple[\s=].*(?:[\r\n]\s*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9bH4c/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `market\.fruit\.apple` - the keyword
- `[\s=]` - **a whitespace or `=` char**
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:[\r\n]\s*)?` - an optional sequence of a CR or LF line break char and then any 0 or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with this RegEx. First, the dot in your string is interpreted as the "any single character" token, not the literal dot. It needs to be escaped with a backslash: `\.`. Next, the non-capturing group in the end to match whitespace is optional, and the `.*` before it will just continue matching characters until it finds a new line. I also don't understand the purpose of the first negative lookbehind.

As to how to fix it, here is my suggestion:

1- If you need to compare the line with a string literal and you are not using any of the RegEx features, you can just read the lines and filter them as such:

```py
lines = open_file.readlines()
lines = [line for line in lines if line != s]
```

2- If you need it in Regex, you can simply replace the non-capturing groups with `^` and `$`, signifying start and end of line, respectively. The new RegEx will be `^market\.fruit\.apple$`, and you can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/pi7Wjw/1/

Make sure to also check the [re library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) for more info about how to use the various special symbols.